# ODE: how to prove this "lifespan" problem?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose $f(t,x)$ is defined on $(\alpha,\beta)\times \Bbb R$, $-\infty<\alpha<\beta<+\infty)$ and is continuous, $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ is also continuous and satisfies
$$|\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}|\le N <+\infty,\, \forall [a,b]\subset (\alpha,\beta)$$
Prove that for each solution $\phi(t)$ to the DE
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t}=f(t,x)$$
the maximal interval of existence (or, informally speaking, its "lifespan") is exactly $(\alpha,\beta)$

Here's how far I've got and where I' m stuck:

Let $D:=(\alpha,\beta)\times \Bbb R$, since $D$ is open, and $f$ is obviously locally Lipschitz continuous w.r.t. $x$ on $E$, we have the following theorem:

> **Theorem** If $\phi(t)$ is a solution of lifespan $(\gamma,\delta)\subset (\alpha,\beta)$, then for $\delta$ there are only three possible cases (and the three cases for $\alpha$ are similar)
>   1). $\delta=+\infty$.
>   2). $\delta<+\infty$ and $\limsup_{t\to \delta-0}|\phi(t)|=+\infty$.
>   3). $\delta<+\infty$ and $\limsup_{t\to \delta-0}|\phi(t)|<+\infty$, but $\lim_{t\to\delta-0}\text{dist}((t,x(t)),\partial D)=0$

Suppose $\phi(t)$ is a solution of lifespan $(\gamma,\delta)\subsetneq (\alpha,\beta)$, and suppose $\delta<\beta$, then I want to find a contradiction with the aid of the theorem above. By my assumption, case one and case three are readily excluded, so we only have to look at case two. By the DE, we have, for some $\gamma<t_0<\delta$:
$$\phi(t)-\phi(t_0)=\int_{t_0}^{t}f(s,\phi(s))\mathrm{d}s$$
and thus 
$$|\phi(t)-\phi(t_0)|\le \int_{t_0}^{t}|f(s,\phi(s))|\mathrm{d}s$$
If we can show RHS is bounded independent of $t$ then we are done, since $LHS$ is unbounded when $t\to \delta-0$. But it is hard for me to control the integral (or particularly the integrand). I have tried using the splitting technique
$$|f(s,\phi(s))|\le |f(s,\phi(s))-f(s,\phi(t_0))|+|f(s,\phi(t_0))|$$
Now the second term is easy to control ($<+\infty$) since $f(t,x)$ is continuous on the closed segment $\{(t,\phi(t_0)), t\in [t_0,\delta]\}$. For the first term, note that $|f'_x|\le N$, we have
$$|f(s,\phi(s))-f(s,\phi(t_0))|\le N |\phi(s)-\phi(t_0)|$$
but it seems still impossible to control $\phi(s)$.

So the most difficult part is to put an uniform bound on $|f(s,\phi(s))|$ for $s\in [t_0,\delta)$. Is there any way to do this?

Best regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your calculations
$$
|\phi(t)-\phi(t_0)|\le\int_{t_0}^{t}|f(s,\phi(t_0)|\,ds+N\int_{t_0}^{t}|\phi(s)-\phi(t_0)|\,ds
$$
$f(s,\phi(t_0))$ is continuous on $(\alpha,\beta)$. Since $\delta<\beta$ it is bounded on $[t_0,\delta)$. Now use Gronwal's inequality to prove that $|\phi(t)-\phi(t_0)|$ is bounded on $[t_0,\delta)$.

Comment: Thanks it works! I've also worked out an approach by myself using a uniform convergent sequence $$\phi_0(t):=\phi(t_0),\, \phi_n(t):=\int_{t_0}^{t} f(s,\phi_{n-1}(s))\mathrm d s$$ over each $[t_0,T]\subset [t_0,\delta)$. The limit function $\phi_{\infty}(t)$ it converges to is exactly the solution $\phi(t)$.  I obtained an uniform bound for $\phi_{\infty}(T)$ and thus made a contradiction, which might be in the same spirit as the Gronwall inequality technique!